# mysql select * Where and get costume row from one field

Tags: mysql, select

I have Table with name person.sql

```
======================================
id      name            address

1       jhon            CA
2       alex            FL
3       adam            NY
4       max             SF
5       robert          AL
6       mat             AK
7       emet            CO
8       frank           HI
9       ian             IL
10      fredy           KS
===================================
```

my problem is can't get costume row using where id
if i want only get id like 1 2 5 8 10 how to implemented ?

im using this query but return empty

```
SELECT * from tbl person where id='1' AND id='2' AND id='5' AND id='8' AND id='10'
```

please help for this :(

Comment: use `where id in( 1, 2, 5, 8, 10 )` ... Is your requirement something beyond this ???

Comment: replace `AND` by `OR`

Comment: thanks @RavinderReddy it's work..thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for WHERE the id is IN your collection, so:    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 3, 5, 8)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from tbl person where id='1' OR id='2' OR id='5' OR id='8' OR id='10'
```